# Reset Django registration models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration

I am trying to implement django registration-redux 1.2. I installed the application and added to it settings.py of my project. I ran manage.py syncdb as well as makemigrations/migrate. Typing these commands again and I get no changes detected. However it seems like the tables are not getting created. When I try to register I get the following error:

ProgrammingError at /main/register/ (1146, "Table 'la_test_serve.registration_registrationprofile' doesn't exist")

Is there a way to reset the project/app so that these tables get created?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 2):

Try to run schemamigration for your registration apps

> python manage.py schemamigration registration --initial

after that run migrate

> python manage.py migrate registration

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app from your "INSTALLED APPS" setting. Then run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`. Reinstall the app.
Note: If you didn't add 'registration' (yes, simply 'registration') to your "INSTALLED APPS", it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error occurred when I was reinstalling django-registration-redux.

Either way, check that you have deleted not only the table for registration in the database but also ensure that in the migrations table delete the corresponding row, in this case 'registration'.